# How to declare a button from another activity in the main one in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I have a problem with accessing a button from another activity. I was searching all over the internet and the best I found is this:

```
View inflatedView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_songcontrol, null);
final Button playNpauseBtn = (Button)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.pauseNplayBtn);`
```

When I click the button nothing happens and I get `mSecurityInputMethodService is null` in logcat

Comment: That's not how Android app development works. One activity does not directly interact with another one.

Comment: You can't access views of one activity in another.  Your code you posted would create a new copy of the layout, with new views.  If you need to return a value to the previous activity, use startActivityForResult and send back an intent.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much!

Comment: You can rather use shared preference or intents to send data from one activity to another. Using this, you can send a flag variable to your main activity, where you need to check for the flag variable and declare the button accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this approach is not recommended. It's best to have a layout that can include another layout to reuse the same button